# Getting the wrong header in my CSVWriter (CsvHelper)

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I'm attempting to write an header to my CSV writer but I am receiving the wrong value for the header, 
my code is as below:

The definition class:

```
public class PersonDefinition
{
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping class:

```
public sealed class PersonDefinitionMap : CsvClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonDefinitionMap()
    {

        Map(m => m.First_Name).Name("First Name");
    }
}
```

In the main program:

```
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(csvFilePath))
{
    var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer);
    csvWriter.Configuration.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;             
    csvWriter.WriteHeader<PersonDefinition>();   
}
```

But the output csv get me the following:

```
First_Name
```

Instead my expected

```
First Name
```

(Without the space)

Where is the problem here?

Comment: Can you show us the code for `WriteHeader<>()`? It's currently missing, and it seems like the most important part.

Comment: It's built in the library CsvHelper (external)

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that was a library name. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you haven't registered the mapping.

```
var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer);
csvWriter.Configuration.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;             
csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<PersonDefinitionMap>(); // <-- here
csvWriter.WriteHeader<PersonDefinition>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [documentation](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/mapping), you need to register the class map:

```
var csv = new CsvReader( textReader );
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MyClassMap>();
```

Or in your case:

```
var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer);
csvWriter.Configuration.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;  
csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<PersonDefinitionMap>();             
csvWriter.WriteHeader<PersonDefinition>();
```